# Conditional evaluation bigquery UDF

Tags: javascript, sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm passing some values to UDF and checking to see if they are between a range, I pass that range as well.
My two parameters: P5->1 , P10->2 . I'm applying this function on a column of integer.
I'm getting an odd outcome from this snippet below:

```
(INPUT > P5 && INPUT <= P10)
```

INPUT: 117

P5: 1

P10:2

RETURNED: TRUE
(ALL ABOVE VALUES WERE CONFIRMED BY OUTPUTTING THEM DIRECTLY)

So instead I attempted with the parameters:

```
(INPUT > 1 && INPUT <= 2)
```

INPUT: 117

RETURNED: FALSE

FULL CODE:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION label2(INPUT INT64, P5 INT64, P10 INT64)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js
"""
if (INPUT > P5 && INPUT <= P10){
return 'B1'
}else{
return false
}
""";
SELECT A.COLUMN , LABEL2(A.COLUMN,1,2)
FROM ... AS A
```

AS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is because INT64 is **unsupported** as an input type for JavaScript UDFs. So your input values are treated as STRINGs which leads to result you see

Instead, use FLOAT64 to represent integer values as a number

So, your UDF should look as below

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION label2(INPUT FLOAT64, P5 FLOAT64, P10 FLOAT64)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS
"""
if (INPUT > P5 && INPUT <= P10){
  return 'B1'
} else {
  return false
}
""";
```